# Encapsulation packet in byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, sockets, tcp

I'm building an C# library for applications who needs communication over TCP/IP using the CIP-protocol. (This is an industrial protocol, used by PLC's). My library is based on an open source VB.net project.

[image]

I found a lot of information at the Microsoft developer network to setup the socket. Next step is to register the session, so I need to receive information using the **Socket.Receive method**. Again, lots of useful information on the developer network.

I'm building the header like this:

```
private string Build_Header(byte[] Command, int Length) //Build the encapsulate message header. The header is 24 bytes fixed length and includes the command and the length of the optional data portion
    {
        string Header;
        byte[] HeaderStatus = { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };
        byte[] HeaderOption = { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 };

        try
        {
            Header = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Command);
            Header += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Length));
            Header += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(SessionID));
            Header += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(HeaderStatus);
            Header += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Context));
            Header += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(HeaderOption);

            return Header;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to create header: {0}", ex);
            return "FAILED";
        }
    }
```

Witch is a copy of the VB function:

```
Private Function _build_header(Command As Byte(), length As Short)
    'Build the encapsulate message header
    'The header is 24 bytes fixed length, and includes the command and the length of the optional data portion.
    Dim header As String
    Try
        header = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Command)                             '# Command UINT
        header += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(length))      '# Length UINT
        header += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(_session))    '# Session Handle UDINT
        header += Encoding.Unicode.GetString({&H0, &H0, &H0, &H0})               '# Status UDINT
        header += Encoding.Unicode.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(_Context))    '# Sender Context 8 bytes
        header += Encoding.Unicode.GetString({&H0, &H0, &H0, &H0})               '# Option UDINT
        'If Not DisableLogFile Then Console.WriteLine("Header created: " + Bytes_To_String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(header)) + "  , length: " _
        '                    + header.Length.ToString + "   (must be equal to 24 bytes)")
        Return header
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to create header: " + ex.Message)
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

But I'm receiving an error message as status "Unsupported encapsulation protocol revision." So I started debugging, line after line and found the following difference:

Original (VB):

[image: VB]

Copy (C#):

[image]

I'm not sure if this is the main problem, but I at least it should be the same format I guess?

Comment: That's a red herring; both strings contain the same data. The display of it is simply different. If you receive a protocol error, your client and server don't agree on what to send and receive.

Comment: Is there a way that I can get both strings in the same format, so I can check if the content is exactly the same?

Comment: @Belekz Use the Immediate Window and just enter `Header`, it will display the actual (unescaped) value

Comment: Can I check: are you saying that one of these VB/C# works and one is broken? if so: which is which? Or does neither work? Personally, I'm **very** suspicious of those `Encoding.Unicode.GetString` calls - this appears to be a binary framing protocol, so why are there string ecodings in the mix?

Comment: "My library is based on an open source VB.net project." ... and: does the reference source here actually work?

Comment: Best to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to debug.  The sniffer will give better error messages than your c# application.  Most likely a count or CRC is wrong giving the error.  The sniffer will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: The reference project (VB.net) is working well. When I asked the programmer why he used the `Encoding.unicode` he told me that this was necessary in order to get the message in the correct format.

Comment: @Belekz he is wrong; I've found the specification, and whoever wrote that VB code has *completely misunderstood* binary encoding protocols. The fact that it is working *at all* right now is completely by chance - they're lucky the encoder didn't corrupt the data. They are doing it **very wrong**. This is not good code to copy, even if it works. I say this as someone with extensive experience implementing binary network protocols. Lets be 100% clear: this method **should not return `string`**. This data **is not text**.

Comment: I second Marc. You should look for another implementation or completely do it yourself from scratch. Then at least you are making your own mistakes. And when you are done and feel like it, maybe post a fixing pull request to the project ...

Comment: @MarcGravell, hm oke, I do believe you, the guy just an PLC engineer like me. If we can't use a string, what do you recommend to prepare messages?

Comment: What the protocol expects: an array of byte. It has a fixed length so it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Fildor IMO `BinaryWriter` is useless and inappropriate for implementing network protocols. The only time `BinaryWriter` is useful is when you don't care what it looks like as long as you can consume it with `BinaryReader`. In this case we **very much do care** what it looks like.

Comment: @Belekz "If we can't use a string, what do you recommend to prepare messages?" - I've put that in an answer

Comment: @MarcGravell You are correct. Taking that back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oof; where to start. K: I'll be frank - the VB reference material you are copying from *is garbage*. It is 100% wrong and anything that is working right now is completely by chance. For starters, this data **is not text** - it is a binary frame. Thus, you **cannot** return `string`. Returning a `byte[]` would be reasonable. Thus, the most important question perhaps is not "how should I get this string", but rather "once I have this string, how am I writing it to the socket"? That code isn't shown in your question, but I'd happily wager that *how you're writing the string to the socket* is the key difference between the two versions.

But: you *shouldn't be dealing with strings in the first place*. Let's say that method returned a `byte[]`. Then we have:

```
byte[] header = BuildHeader(command, length);
```

Now there's only one way we can write a `byte[]` to the stream (unless we get very imaginitive):

```
socket.Send(header, 0, header.Length);
```

(or some similar variant involving a `Stream`)

Now; what `BuildHeader` *should* be doing is something like:

```
byte[] header = new byte[24];
// .. fill in
return header;
```

As for what those parts should be: it depends on the *endianness*; it looks like `UINT` is 2 bytes and `UDINT` is 4. So to give an example of writing `length` (the second field, 2 bytes, offset 2 bytes), that will be *either*:

```
header[2] = (byte)length;
header[3] = (byte)(length >> 8);
```

or

```
header[2] = (byte)(length >> 8);
header[3] = (byte)length;
```

Unfortunately `BitConverter.GetBytes` doesn't help you pack a buffer, as a: it doesn't allow you to pass a buffer and offset in, and b: the endianness is defined **by your CPU** (and we need it to be a specific endianness). If the VB code works, it is probably little-endian (unless you have an Itanium), so the first version (little end first) should be correct.

Repeat that for all the fields, and you'll have a valid header.

Comment: ah, update: I found this in the spec: "Multi-byte integer fields in the encapsulation messages shall be transmitted in little-endian byte
order." - so yeah, I was right - little-endian

Comment: What does the `(byte)(length >>8)` ?

Comment: @Belekz "right shift"; we're trying to pack 16 bits of data into 2 bytes; the `(byte)length` takes the lowest 8 bits and just drops the rest (assuming that you haven't enabled `checked` mode) - so let's say our `length` is `814`; in (big-endian) binary that is `00000011 00101110`. The `(byte)length` gives us the `00101110` (46 as a decimal) that we shove into the first byte. `>> 8` means "move all the bits 8 places to the right" (dropping any as needed) - leaving us `00000011` (3 as a decimal). So: the little-endian encoding of 814 is (in decimals): 46, 3

Comment: Oke, so "Session Handle" is an uDint = 4 bytes. Then Header[4] = (byte) Session. Header[5] = (byte) (Session >> 8). Header[6] = (byte) (session >> 16). Header[7] = (byte) (session >> 24). Correct?

Comment: @Belekz perfect!

Comment: One last question, in order to send a session request, I need to add data after the header we just made. How can I 'merge' two bytes after each other? 
When it was a string a could use an `+=` operand, but this doesn't work for bytes of course...

Comment: @Belekz worth using short instead of int for "length", since it's 2 bytes in your protocol (so int range is much bigger than what you need).

Comment: @Belekz three options there: 1: you allocate a second buffer of the size you want, and simply have two calls to Send/Write; 2: you allocate a single buffer at the start that is the right size for both - and pass it *into* the two methods for them to add their bits; 3: you get all complex with buffer pools etc so you never allocate anything - that's at the extreme hardcore end :)

Comment: Ok I think option 2 fits the most for me. Thanks a lot men! You saved days of work for me today!